# Mysql Query to match column data (JSON) partially

Tags: java, mysql, json

I have a Table in which there is column having data in form of string which is actually a JSON.
Now i want to match this string partially with another string (JSON) which may or may not be having some text.

Forexample,
In database I have a column value as :

```
 {"returnEnabled":true,"immediateRpi":true,"crmMessages":[null],"selfServeMessages":[null],"returnType":"refund,replacement"}
```

Now, it should match with input text :

```
{"returnEnabled":true,"immediateRpi":true,"returnType":"refund,replacement"}
```

No matter what is the value of other elements

Any suggestions.

Comment: while fetching from database just select columns you want , did you try this or just asked the question ??

Comment: Convert both strings to JSON objects and start comparing.

Comment: Hello @J Santosh Above given data is a single column value